Response of model anthropic.claude-3-sonnet being truncated- using refine chain with chatbedrock langchain
I am working on extracting and summarizing records from many documents (txt and word file) using ChatBedrock of langchain and aws model "anthropic.claude-3-sonnet". I am passing model in load_qa_chain  and refine as it's type.  I am also passing documents in chunk using RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter. Response is being truncated without any reason. Although those truncated response have many information (many tokens).
At first I was using stuff type chain but got this issue of answer being truncated. ALthough now I am using refine chain response output is still being truncated in between even after changing parameter like max_tokens.
Defincation of model in code
from langchain_aws import ChatBedrock

def get_chatbedrock_model(bedrock_client):
    return ChatBedrock(
        model_id="anthropic.claude-3-sonnet-20240229-v1:0",
        model_kwargs={
            "max_tokens": 4096,
            "temperature": 0.0,
            "top_p": 0.01
        },
        client=bedrock_client,
    )

below is the refined code for one section of chain defination and prompt. In project, I am running 5 chains for different prompt to get diffrent details from documents.
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
prompt_defination = """You are an expert..."""
prompt = PromptTemplate(
     input_variables=["summaries"], template=problem_list_name_dob
)


import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain


config = Config(read_timeout=1000)
bedrock_client = boto3.client(
    service_name="bedrock-runtime", region_name="us-east-1",
    config=config
)
llm_model = get_chatbedrock_model(bedrock_client)
search_chain = load_qa_chain(llm=llm_model, chain_type="refine")

code for document chunking
def chunk_doc(document, file_full_path):
    input_documents = []
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
        # Set a really small chunk size, just to show.
        chunk_size=60000,
        chunk_overlap=200,
        length_function=len,
        is_separator_regex=False,
    )
    documents = text_splitter.create_documents([document])
    for doc in documents:
        # doc.metadata = {"source": signed_url_document.split("?")[0]}
        doc.page_content = doc.page_content + f"\n\n Source: {file_full_path} \n\n"
        input_documents.append(doc)
    return input_documents


input_documents = []
for each_file_path in os.listdir(f"data/{object_name}/"):
    file_full_path = f"data/{object_name}/{each_file_path}"
    if file_full_path.endswith('.txt'):
        input_documents.appends(chunk_doc(read_txt_file(file_full_path), file_full_path))
    elif file_full_path.endswith('.doc') or file_full_path.endswith('.docx'):
        input_documents.appends(chunk_doc(read_doc_file(file_full_path), file_full_path))


running chain code
search_kwargs = {
            "input_documents": input_documents,
        }
output = search_chain.run(input_documents=input_documents, question=prompt)

I also did used chunking part to fix answer being truncated issue. I also changed max_token parameter to 150000,4096, 200000,4000.. But there are many times that answer is being truncated. I am not able to see what is the issue here. Please feel free to give suggestions if you have dealt with it or know the solution.

I have limited knowledge here, but I think tokens are calculated as input tokens plus output tokens that make the total tokens for that interaction. So if you pass in 3000 tokens but you are expecting 4000 tokens output becuause your max_tokens is 4096, it may be truncated. In this case, you should expect output tokens to be like 1000 given that you have used up the 3000 during your input.
In one project, when I passed my inputs as .txt, my truncation problem disappeared. I don't know why but I think it handles file formats (.txt, .py, etc.) differently from character chunks.
